# Digital PLL reference noise rejection

Tags: pll, control-loop, control-theory

I have a fully digital implementation of a PLL.
The problem that I have is the white noise coming from the PFD (you can view it as input jitter). I would like to filter it a lot, but an implementation with a PI controller lead to a slope of just a -20 dB/decade of noise rejection coming from the PFD.

Is it possible to improve it? The constrain that I have is on the rejection of the VCO Noise, which should have a slope of about 40dB/decade below the control loop bandwidth

The digital model is composed by:

PFD = Kpfd

VCO (include a delay of 1 sample) = $$
\frac{Kvco * T_s}{z-1}\
$$

PI = $$ 
\frac{(K_p+K_i)*z - K_p}{z -1}
$$
L = PFD * PI  * VCO

The input noise rejection function is $$
\frac{L}{1+L}
$$
The VCO noise rejection function is $$
\frac{1}{1+L}
$$

The currently used values are Kp=1500, Ki=20, Kpfd=2600 and Kvco=0.15 with a Ts=250us.
I would like to have a  L/(1+L) response above the cut-off frequeny above -20 dB/decade

Thank you!

Comment: much is possible depending on the details. Post the details.

Comment: what is stopping you from low-passing the forward path?